# Photo Frame Sample - Light Red Shade and Text Align Center

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to create a photo frame where there will be a light red shade and a text aligned center. I am taking the actual size of the images and then trying to create the new image programmatically with the frame. Below is a sample that I did so far:

[image]

In the image, there is a white border that I've used for demonstration purpose. I want the light red shade should not go over the white border and the text should be exactly in the middle for every image. As I am working with the actual image size, the shade and text does not remain in the specific position. In some images, the light red shade and text does not show up.  I did the following code to make it work but seem like missing something:

```
$size = getimagesize($file_tmp); //Gets the image file size     
$width = $size[0];      
$height = $size[1];

$images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tmp); //Creates jpeg image from tmp file location      
$photoX = imagesx($images_orig);      
$photoY = imagesy($images_orig);        
$images_fin = imageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
$color = imagecolorallocate($images_fin, 255, 255, 255);
$lightRed = imagecolorallocatealpha($images_fin, 255, 0, 0, 100);   
$black = imagecolorallocate($images_fin, 0, 0, 0);          
$text = 'I am from China';      
$font = 'MyriadPro-Light.ttf';

$positions_redline = ($height / 4)*3;

ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $photoX, $photoY);     
Imagefilledrectangle($images_fin, 0, $positions_redline, $width, $height, $lightRed);     

$font_size = 10;        

/*Starts - This is what I tried to fit the text into the image specifically in the center*/
$bbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $text); 
$tbwidth = $bbox[2];
$factor = round(($width / $tbwidth), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);   
$newFontSize = $font_size * $factor;   
/*Finishes - This is what I tried to fit the text into the image specifically in the center*/ 


print_r($bbox[2]);
print_r("<br/>".$factor);          

// Get your Text Width and Height
$text_width = $bbox[2] - $bbox[6];
$text_height = $bbox[3] - $bbox[7];
// Calculate coordinates of the text    

$x = ($photoX / 2) - ($text_width / 2);
$y = (($height - $positions_redline) / 2) - ($text_height / 2);

Imagettftext($images_fin, $newFontSize, 0, $x, $y + $positions_redline, $color, $font , $text); //Trying to write text and align it center here
$new_images = 'testImageResult.jpg';
ImageJPEG($images_fin,"Images/".$new_images);
```

Comment: Are u try my source? xD

Comment: The light red shade works perfectly but the fonts are not shown properly. I am sharing two samples where the font size are not the same: i) https://postimg.org/image/ns3jqgpoh/ ii) https://postimg.org/image/3k7t49wkh/. Is there any way to make the font size same or look in an appropriate way and size? By the way, do you have any idea about how to add apps in facebook? If possible, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: This function  imagettfbbox in PHP not working well so you get this issue. Please choose one best font so you will have best result. With App Facebook? You can please read more Grap Facebook API

Comment: If can, can you please vote up my answer and accept it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Quỳnh! Thanks again for the answer you provided. It is really helpful but need a slight change in it. I tried to make the text fit into the image specifically in the center. But the above code makes the text at the right hand side of the image. Here is a sample: https://postimg.org/image/b23zg750h/ and I've updated the code. Do have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this source

```
    $file_tmp = '/var/www/html/testGuzzle/testImage.jpg';
    $size = getimagesize($file_tmp); //Gets the image file size     
    $width = $size[0];      
    $height = $size[1];

    $images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_tmp); //Creates jpeg image from tmp file location      
    $photoX = imagesx($images_orig);      
    $photoY = imagesy($images_orig);        
    $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($images_fin, 255, 255, 255);
    $lightRed = imagecolorallocatealpha($images_fin, 255, 0, 0, 100);   
    $black = imagecolorallocate($images_fin, 0, 0, 0);          
    $text = 'Im from VietNam';      
    $font = '/var/www/html/testGuzzle/OpenSans-SemiboldItalic.ttf';

    $positions_redline = ($height/4)*3;

    ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $photoX, $photoY);     
    Imagefilledrectangle($images_fin, 0, $positions_redline, $width, $height, $lightRed);     

    $font_size = 20;
    $bbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $text);
    print_r($bbox);
    // Get your Text Width and Height
    $text_width = $bbox[2]-$bbox[0];
    $text_height = $bbox[7]-$bbox[1];
    // Calculate coordinates of the text

    $x = ($photoX/2) - ($text_width/2);
    $y = ($height-$positions_redline)/2) - ($text_height/2);

    Imagettftext($images_fin, 40, 0, $x, $y+$positions_redline, $color, $font , $text); //Trying to write text and align it center here
    $new_images = 'testImageResult.jpg';
    ImageJPEG($images_fin,"/var/www/html/testGuzzle/".$new_images);
```